# Expanding a slice's size to prevent slice bounds out of range error

Tags: go

I have written the following:

```
func main() {
    //inside main        
        fileInputBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/test")
        byteSize2 := len(fileInputBytes)

        var inputFileByteSlice = fileInputBytes[0:]
        var numberOfIndexes = math.Floor(float64(byteSize / indexingOffset))

        for i := 1; i <= int(numberOfIndexes); i++ {
            // adding i to the indexer insures that we use lookahed to ignore previously inserted indexing values
            var v int = (i * indexingOffset) + i
            Insert(&inputFileByteSlice, v+i, indexingByteValue)
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
    //outside main
    //variation of https://blog.golang.org/slices with pointers and such
        func Insert(slice *[]byte, index int, value byte) {
            // Grow the slice by one element.
            (*slice) = (*slice)[0 : len(*slice)+1]
            // Use copy to move the upper part of the slice out of the way and open a hole.
            copy((*slice)[index+1:], (*slice)[index:])
            // Store the new value.
            (*slice)[index] = value
            // Return the result.
        }
```

The `slice bounds out of range` error is getting on my nerves. The length of the slice grows outside of the size and overflows, the reason I don't understand is that I thought the call to 'grow' the slice by one element(before copy) will dynamically allocate more space. Since that is not the case, can anyone offer me a better suggestion?

Comment: You're converting an `int` to a `float64`, then using `math.Floor` on what is already an even integer value, then converting it back to an `int`. None of that does anything useful, just use the original integer division result.

Comment: @JimB Good catch, that was rather amateur of me

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a slice is already a reference type. So you don't need to pass its pointer around if you are not going to change its capacity. So your `main` can be simplified as:

```
func main() {
    fileInputBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/test")
    byteSize2 := len(fileInputBytes)

    // No need to use pointer to slice. If you want a brand new slice
    // that does not affect the original slice values, use copy()
    inputFileByteArray := fileInputBytes
    var numberOfIndexes = math.Floor(float64(byteSize / indexingOffset))

    for i := 1; i <= int(numberOfIndexes); i++ {
        var v int = (i * indexingOffset) + i

        // Insert needs to return the newly updated slice reference
        // which should be assigned in each iteration.
        inputFileByteArray = Insert(inputFileByteArray, v+i, indexingByteValue)
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Then, the `Insert` function can be simplified simply by using `append` along with `copy` and returning the newly created slice:

```
func Insert(slice []byte, index int, value byte) []byte {
    if index >= len(slice) {
        // add to the end of slice in case of index >= len(slice)
        return append(slice, value)
    }
    tmp := make([]byte, len(slice[:index + 1]))
    copy(tmp, slice[:index])
    tmp[index] = value
    return append(tmp, slice[index:]...)
}
```

This may not be the best implementation but it is simple enough. Example usage at: https://play.golang.org/p/Nuq4RX9XQD

Comment: You don't need to make the temp slice, the documented method for slice insertion is fine (you can keep the short circuit if you'd like). I also wouldn't accept an invalid index value and return the incorrect result. Indexing out of range should panic or at least provide an error, not silently create the wrong slice. https://play.golang.org/p/dLeNTmYKM7

Comment: @JimB can you explain why my original attempt to 'grow' the slice was not instantiating a new slice with larger memory capacity?

Comment: @abhink The reason I utilized pointers to the original slice was I wanted to limit my memory footprint. Do you think there is anyway to expand without copying to a new slice everytime? Also, JimB stated that you could go without the tmp declaration. If that is true I am assuming it would be viable to just declare:  copy(tmp, slice[:index+1])  ?

Comment: @Rice Since you are doing random insertions to your array, it'll always be linear time. Because arrays (or slices here) are contiguous blocks of memory, you cannot insert something in the middle without moving every subsequent element of the array one place over. So extensive copying will be required. If you don't need random access (i.e. slice element access is always linear, from beginning to end), you can try using a linked list type structures. Also, JimB's answer is similar to mine but better implemented so use that if you have to.

Comment: @abhink Thank you so much for the guided example/explanation. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your function only works if the slice happens to have enough initial capacity. If you need more capacity, you can only "grow" the slice using the `append` function. You can still use the `*[]byte` pointer argument to modify the slice in place like so:

```
func Insert(slice *[]byte, index int, value byte) {
    *slice = append(*slice, 0)
    copy((*slice)[index+1:], (*slice)[index:])
    (*slice)[index] = value
}
```

However, it's more customary to return a new slice value, and reassign it each time. This gives you a similar function signature to the builtin `append`.

```
func Insert(slice []byte, index int, value byte) []byte {
    slice = append(slice, 0)
    copy(slice[index+1:], slice[index:])
    slice[index] = value
    return slice
}
```

Comment: By your logic (in the second function you wrote), the memory capacity also grows by the use of append?

Comment: @Rice: I'm not sure what you mean. These 2 functions are basically identical, and only differ in how you call them.

Comment: Sorry I need to be more specific. My simple need (originally) was to grow the actual memory capacity of the slice, not just the length. Will append do the job?

Comment: @Rice: that's what append does. You can't grow the length beyond capacity, without increasing the capacity.